# How to add support for Domain specific language developed using Xtext in Eclipse Che?

Tags: eclipse-che, eclipse-orion

We have our domain specific language developed over Xtext. We want to add this language support on Eclipse Che.

**Question 1**: What are the possible ways to add ?

I know Eclipse che uses Orion as editor. As per Xtext documentation at http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/330_web_support.html, it says XText supports Orion. It means Che can support Xtext without doing anything but che is planning to support XText via Xtext Language Server protocol installed.

**Question 2:** How this Xtext language server protocol can be used for existing Xtext code?

**Question 3:** Does Orion also communicate with Xtext via LSP ?

Any help/pointer will be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i cannot really answer (1) and (3) but (2)

- Che is working on Language Server support: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gp08vRPwSGU . inside the code there are already some language servers hooked into che e.g. https://github.com/eclipse/che/tree/e079338a11905dbe2a73bc7b5b034d40e02b72d1/plugins/plugin-json/che-plugin-json-server
- Xtext will have Support for Language Servers in the upcoming 2.11 versions. The Following blog articles will give you a starting point: https://blogs.itemis.com/en/integrating-xtext-language-support-in-visual-studio-code (code at https://github.com/itemis/xtext-languageserver-example) and https://github.com/TypeFox/languageserver-example . the basic idea is that (a) xtext will generate language registations to META-INF/services/* for Java Servers and ships with a main class to start a language server in process io mode 
  `org.eclipse.xtext.ide.server.ServerLauncher`. alternatively you can start a language server in socket mode.
- Eclipse Orion is currently working on Language Server Support as well http://git.eclipse.org/c/orion/org.eclipse.orion.client.git/log/?h=mrennie/languageServer

Comment: Thanks Christian. Do we have any steps/ documentation for communication between Xtext Beta LSP and Che Client? How it can achieve EMF features?

Comment: No but if the current language server stuff calls an external java process and the vscode examples of xtext do the same than it should be transposable from vscode to Che

Comment: In our scenario, XText generates the Eclipse Modeling framework (EMF Model). We use this EMF model and have controller around it. Controller has lot many code.
If we use same XText code, how it will work with Che? Is our Controller code will get reused?

Comment: No idea there is nothing final

Comment: what does your controller do?